# Object.keys(data).length counting items and not entries

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
{id: "001", name="name 1", lastname="lastname 1", active="0"}
```

In order to get the number of entries...which in this example above should be 1 I've added this code:

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

This is returning 4 and not 1.

What I'm I doing wrong here?enter code here

Comment: Why should it returns 1 ? You have 4 keys in your object ...

Comment: I need to count the number of records which is 1. How can I get this instead?

Comment: Do you have an array of records which may contain only the one object shown? If so you just need `yourArrayName.length`.

Comment: You have an object, sure thing it has only one record, it may thou store more records in  array property..

Comment: There is no such thing inside your code (which is not valid, BTW). If you have an array, you can check its length property but if you are handling a single object, well you are handling just one object...

Comment: Cause your code search for keys if you want to search for entries so get the length of parent array without use of Object.keys() , I think you have array of objects and you want to see how many objects within it

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem and give a description  (and the actual output) on what the expected output would be for the given input. Right now it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, that is the expected behavior of `Object.keys()`, as it returns an array of properties of the `object` passed. But you are expecting the length of an array of such objects.
eg: -

```
let arr = [
  {id: "001", name="name 1", lastname="lastname 1", active="0"},
];
console.log(arr.length); // It outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is returning 4 and not 1 because your `data` is not an array.

```
var arrays = [];
var data = {"id": "001", "name"="name 1", "lastname"="lastname 1", "active"="0"};
arrays.push(data);
console.log(array.length);//  will print 1
```

and

```
Object.keys(data).length // will return 4
```

Answer (score -1):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   property

Check this out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21007006)

Comment: The essential part of the answer is highlighted as a first line of the answer and the link provided is a mozilla documentation which almost never changes. That should not be a reason for downvote.